# Error occurred when installing package 'lxml'

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, lxml

ERROR: b'\n\nAgreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run \xe2\x80\x9csudo xcodebuild -license\xe2\x80\x9d and then retry this command.\n\n\n'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u2vP.png)

Answer (score 0):

ERROR soloved by install Application Xcode & agree the licence